# Remove case sensitivity in a JS search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list on a page and a search bar that searches and filters the list as the user types. At the moment the input has to be all lowercase (which I've added myself). How can I remove all case sensitivity from the search string? For example if I search for `teST` the result for `Test` would still appear.

```js
var list = $("table.ms-listviewtable");
var listItems = $("table.ms-listviewtable tr:not(.ms-viewheadertr)"); 
var input = $("input#filterInput");

input.keyup(function() {
  listItems.each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (text.indexOf(input.val()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `if (text.indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase()) != -1)`

Comment: This worked, thanks very much! Will also mark the below as correct.

Comment: Please cache the input val. Also I suggest to use toggle: `input.on("input",function() { var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); listItems.each(function() { var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(val)!=-1); }) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `toLowerCase` on `input.val()` as well as `text`.

```
if (text.indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase()) != -1) {...}
```

Also note you can use `includes` instead of `indexOf` on newer browsers:

```
if (text.includes(input.val().toLowerCase())) {...}
```

Comment: But cache input.val()

Comment: What do you mean @mplungjan?

Comment: @JackBashford :  means to keep the value in a variable..... but not necessary in this case since it's only using once

Comment: `input.on("input",function() { var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); listItems.each(function() { var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(val)!=-1); }) })` or `=== 0` from match from start

Comment: @PranavCBalan it is used in each test in the loop

Comment: @mplungjan oops i d'dn't noticed that, ... then it's better to keep in a variable outside the each

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.match` method

```js
var list = $("table.ms-listviewtable");
var listItems = $("table.ms-listviewtable tr:not(.ms-viewheadertr)"); 
var input = $("input#filterInput");

input.keyup(function() {
  let inputVal = input.val().toLowerCase();
  listItems.each(function() {
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().match(inputVal)){
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cache input val and toggle

Comment: @mplungjan: did you mean to move the `input.val()` outside the iterator?

Comment: `input.on("input",function() { var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); listItems.each(function() { var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(val)!=-1); }) })` or `=== 0` to match from start

Comment: Yes, that was the optimized way, corrected!!!

Comment: Upvoted, many thanks!